# Inner object(ArrayList) is not converting to JSON String?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I am facing issue in converting the nested list object to JSON.I am using object mapper and it is only converting the starting values and after that there is one arraylist inside it and it is not going through that list.

I have tried some basic iteration using JsonNode root = mapper.valueToTree(obj)so that i can iterate through the inner arraylist but i am not getting the result.I am new to this parsing conversion.

code snippet--

```
public class JsonUtils {

  public static <T> String toJsonString(final T obj) throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        //JsonNode root = mapper.valueToTree(obj);
        jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return jsonString;
  }

  public static <T> String toJsonString(final List<T> lstObject) throws JSONException, IOException {
    final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (final T object : lstObject) {
        final String json = JsonUtils.toJsonString(object);
        final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
    }
    return jsonArray.toString();
  }
}
```

So here is the result which i am getting -

```
[2, [{"geoMarketId":1,"geoname":"AP","geoId":1,"checked":false}, 
{"geoMarketId":7,"geoname":"EP","geoId":2,"checked":false},
{"geoMarketId":16,"geoname":"Japan","geoId":3,"checked":true},
{"geoMarketId":18,"geoname":"LA","geoId":4,"checked":true},
{"geoMarketId":22,"geoname":"MEA","geoId":5,"checked":true},
{"geoMarketId":24,"geoname":"NA","geoId":6,"checked":false}]]
```

Actual Result which should come-

```
{"geoMarketId":1,"geoname":"AP","geoId":1,"checked":false,
marketName:{"marketname":JP,"marketname":"AP","marketname":MP}}
```

My json conversion is ignoring this inner list in the same index.

Is there any way my json class can iterate and also convert that innerlist to JSON?

Comment: `marketName:{....}` besides the fact that this isn't valid json (though probably a typo and you mean `"marketName"`) the value isn't a list/array. It's hard to tell what the mapper is doing if all we know is the output but you didn't show the input.

Comment: the market name is a list which i am setting in the same class and when i send the whole list to this utils class it is converting only this part--{"geoMarketId":1,"geoname":"AP","geoId":1,"checked":false} here after this there is one marketlist which has value like above  and it is ignoring that list .

Comment: int geoId;
 String geoname;
 int geoMarketId;
 boolean checked;
 
 List<Market> marketList; //this list is in the same class and has values This list is being ignored by the mapper

Comment: Please don't post "code" in a comment but add it (nicely formatted) to your question via an [edit]. Please also consider posting a [mcve] instead of just a few fields. The error might be in the class itself (e.g. wrong/missing mapping or getters) or in the data (you might _think_ there's an element in the list but there might not be).

Comment: There is an arraylist within this mainlist but my JSON utils class is not converting that list into json string.May be JSON Util class is not iterating the list it is taking only the params .Any way i can iterate through my JSON Util class to iterate this innerlist?